# Can Windows 8/8.1 Full Version be used to upgrade Windows 7 install which has lost its product activation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-activation

tl;dr:  Can I buy a Windows 8/8.1 full version disk and use it to upgrade a Windows 7 computer without losing all my programs even if that Windows 7 install is saying it's not a valid copy of Windows (won't activate)?

In 2011 I bought the Windows 7 Family Pack (download only) from the Microsoft Store, which was supposed to allow me to install Windows 7 on up to 3 computers.  (They only ever gave me 1 key, so I assume the one key can be used on up to 3 machines.)  I used it to put Windows 7 on my own PC in 2011, and on my mom's PC in 2013.  In 2014 I tried to use it to downgrade a Windows 8 laptop to Windows 7, but it would not activate so I took Windows 7 off and put Windows 8 back on the laptop.

(Note:  For the two PCs I used two different copies of Windows XP Pro Full which I had to serve as the base install to upgrade from, since the Windows 7 Family pack is an upgrade disk not a full version.)

I had not used my PC for a while when I tried to use it yesterday, Windows 7 on that desktop PC (which was activated 3 years ago) suddenly started saying it isn't a valid copy of Windows anymore, and it won't (re)activate either.  I did change some hardware, but I believe I should be within my rights because it's only on 2 machines and even if changing the hardware counts as a 3rd install I should have 3 anyway.  (The install on the laptop never activated.)

I went through the whole automated phone support thing where you enter the nine groups of numbers and it is supposed to give you a similar code to put in, but after I entered all the numbers it asked me to confirm, "How many computers is this copy of Windows installed on?" I said, "Two," and it said, "You have violated your license terms," and hung up on me.

If I'm going to have to buy Windows again, I might as well buy Windows 8 or 8.1.  It would be nice if I could just do an upgrade so I will not have to reinstall all my programs, however I am worried that if I simply purchase the upgrade edition it won't activate if Windows 7 won't activate.  So I'm wondering if I can buy the full version of Windows 8 but also upgrade instead of reinstall Windows 7.

Comment: Of course it can. You just can't use the tool that is provided with the Upgrade license ( that downloads Windows 8.x ) based on the license key. Since you have the installation media it will work exactly like the Upgrade installation media.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes. **A windows 8.0 Professional Upgrade license will be the cheapest option.**

Comment: Will Win8 Pro Upgrade activate even if the Win7 install it upgrades cannot activate?  Also what if I needed to reinstall - could I go WinXP Pro (which I have) to Win8 Pro upgrade?

Comment: Yes.  You can check other questions to determine if there is an upgrade path from Windows XP to Windows 8.0

Comment: Ultimately I was able to resolve the issue (by re-activating my Windows 7 installation) by speaking with a human from Microsoft's activation phone line, without needing to re-purchase Windows.